# Python ImportError in Django

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь запустить Django проект с такой структурой:

projectx

```
├──apps
│  ├── app1
|  |    ├── __init__.py
|  |    └── ...
│  └── app2
|       ├── __init__.py
|       └── ...
├──project
│  ├── settings.py
│  ├── urls.py
│  ├── __init__.py
|  └── ...
├── manage.py
└── ...
```

Во время запуска:
    `python manage.py runserver` получаю `ImportError: No module named apps`

`$ echo $PYTHONPATH`  gives
/home/alexander/Work/projectx

Django version 1.9.8

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...

'apps.app1',
'apps.app2'
]
```

У коллеги запускается этот проект без изменений, думаю, дело в PYTHONPATH переменной.

Comment: У коллеги точно запускается именно такой проект и именно без файла `apps/__init__.py`? Ибо без него он по идее и не должен запускаться

Comment: @andreymal , Да. Если добавить его, то уже появляются другие ImportError'ы, уже в силу того, что питон ищет что-то первым делом в apps.py, которые лежат ближе, нежели чем в директории apps/

Comment: Значит надо бы и эти другие ImportError'ы приложить тоже